# When posting data containing the text "or #"|| "and #" to PHP from AJAX $_REQUEST Blows up with "Error 403 Forbidden"

Tags: php, ajax, boolean-operations

I have a workaround for this problem but can't for the life of me determine if the problem is in my AJAX or PHP code or if I am just missing something.
I have included the source code that creates an RSS XML feed document. I first create an Object array to store the keyed data that will be supplied to AJAX and then call the PHP script which creates the feed document.  Works perfectly with the following strange boolean operator word exceptions.
1. If any keyed data contains the word 'or' followed by a space followed by any number then the PHP script blows up with error 403 when trying to access $_REQUEST or $_POST variables.
2. If any keyed data contains the word 'and' followed by a space followed by any number then the PHP script blows up with error 403 when trying to access $_REQUEST or $_POST variables.
Here is my code:
**ajax_or_php_bug_main.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ajax or PHP Bug</title>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax_or_php_bug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center_form">
<form class="rss_form" method="post">
<label class="disp">Title: </label><input class="rss_channel_title" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter a title for this feed" /><br/>
<label class="disp">Subtitle: </label><input class="rss_channel_subtitle" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter a subtitle for this feed" /><br/>
<label class="disp">Item Description Lines: </label><textarea class="rss_item_text"></textarea><br/>
<input class="save_button" type="button" value="Save RSS Feed" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax_or_php_bug.js**

```
$(function (){

var feedFilename = 'myfeed.xml';
$('.rss_channel_title').val('My Channel Title');
$('.rss_channel_subtitle').val('My Channel Subtitle');
$('.rss_item_text').val('or 9');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SAVE RSS FEED
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$(".save_button").on('click', function(){
var jsonData=createJSONArray();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "rss_save_feed.php",
data: {feedarray: jsonData},
/*data: "feedarray="+jsonData,*/
datatype: "json",
/*traditional: true,*/
success: function(feed_text){
alert('RETURNED FROM SAVE PHP: '+feed_text);
},
beforeSend:function()
{
}
});
return false;
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create Array of Aruments
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function createJSONArray() {
//alert('in createJSONArray');
var returnObj = new Object();
returnObj.filename = feedFilename;
returnObj.title = $('.rss_channel_title').val();
returnObj.subtitle = $('.rss_channel_subtitle').val();
items = $('.rss_item_text').val();
//items = items.replace(/or/g,"0987654321"); //UNCOMMENT FOR WORKAROUND
//items = items.replace(/and/g,"1234567890"); //UNCOMMENT FOR WORKAROUND
returnObj.items = items;
return returnObj;
}
});
```

**rss_save_feed.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_REQUEST)){
die('Too bad!');
}
//this next line blows with "Error 403 Forbidden" if data contains "or #"||"and #"
//it doesn't matter if the data is an array, xml or text being passed
//not sure if the problem is related to ajax or php???
$args = $_REQUEST['feedarray'];
if($args){
//Create the RSS Feed
$rss = '';
$rss .= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$rss .= '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>';
$rss .= '<rss version="2.0">';
$rss .= '<channel>';
$rss .= '<title>' . $args[title] . '</title>';
$rss .= '<description>' . $args[subtitle] . '</description>';
$rss .= '<pubDate>' . date(DATE_RSS, strtotime("now")) . '</pubDate>';
$rss .= '<location>' . $args[location] . '</location>';
$items = $args[items];
//$items = str_replace("0987654321","or",$items); //UNCOMMENT FOR WORKAROUND
//$items = str_replace("1234567890","and",$items); //UNCOMMENT FOR WORKAROUND
$items = explode("\n",$items);
foreach($items as $item){
$rss .= '<item>';
$rss .= '<description>' . $item . '</description>';
$rss .= '<pubDate>' . date(DATE_RSS, strtotime("now")) . '</pubDate>';
$rss .= '</item>';
}
$rss .= '</channel>';
$rss .= '</rss>';
//file_put_contents($args[filename], $rss);
echo $rss;
}
?>
```

Comment: ive tested and all went ok here...what are the exact values you are populating the form with? what version of php are you using?

Comment: If you replace that with a proper [XML writer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) version you probably won't have any problems. You're note even trying to escape things properly. You're just hoping and praying there's nothing unusual in your input.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely some kind of security module/filter on your web server. What web server are you using? I saw similar problems with IIS and I know there is filter module for nginx. So just check the web server logs.

Comment: I believe it is apache. You know I think you might be right.  I remember watching a youtube video on SQL Injection which showed a WHERE clause like "WHERE email='any_value' OR '1' ='1" which always returns true. Just to be sure I will contact my web provider to confirm such a filter.

Comment: Thank you!!  That is the answer and I will stick with my workaround.  If anyone is interest I found the video that demonstrates SQL injection and my prover has verified filters. Video link: https://exchange.apsva.us/owa/redir.aspx?C=Lin5aQzRHkulv84NPnP4jXoVxmRdRtII9jFs1WOCKaZvATC7ac8oseaGiDhA8U34TyRrtxAQj7w.&URL=https%3a%2f%2fwww.youtube.com%2fwatch%3fv%3d-VwZs-pIIUY . I would imagine if anyone is running the scripts with no errors then maybe they should look into filtering as well.  Anyway thanks again for helping I have been struggling with this for three days.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Opps bad link to video, here is a good one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VwZs-pIIUY

Answer (score 0):

In  ajax_or_php_bug.js replace

```
items = items.replace(/or/g,"0987654321"); 
items = items.replace(/and/g,"1234567890");
```

with this

```
items = items.replace("/or/g","0987654321"); 
 items = items.replace("/and/g","1234567890");
```

Comment: Thanks, Either way the workaround works fine.  The question is what is causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same exact problem happen on my websites hosted by HTTPME.com.  I don't suppose you're using the same web host?  I just opened up a ticket with them asking them to whitelist my websites (or whatever they need to do) because I already have logic in my PHP code to remove any potentially dangerous logic that a user might try to inject.  I had to open up a ticket a couple of months ago for the same sort of thing when I discovered that I could no longer use the word 'exit' (or any words that have the word 'exit' embedded in the larger word) in any of my web forms.  At the time, they told me that it was being triggered by a ModSecurity rule.